# Join query that only retrieves 1 rows matched

Tags: sql-server, join, having-clause

I have the following two tables:

**User**

- UserID
- Name
- Type

**UserCompany**

- CompanyID
- UserID

**Company**

- CompanyID
- Name

I want to have all companies that have only 1 user with type 5.

Why is this query not working?

```
SELECT C.Name FROM USER u 
JOIN UserCompany UC on u.UserID = UC.UserID 
JOIN Company C on uc.companyID = c.companyID
WHERE u.Type = 5
GROUP BY u.name
HAVING COUNT(u.name) = 1
```

**SAMPLE DATA**

User Table:

```
1 John 1
2 Beth 2 
3 Mike 5
4 John 5
```

Company table:

```
1 XYZ 
2 KBC
3 MMM
```

UserCompany

```
1 1 
1 3
1 4
2 3
2 1
```

=> Company 2 should be returned because it only has 1 user that has type 5

Comment: how many rows do you have in each table, could you provide some sample data to work with?

Comment: Hi Rich Benner, thanks for your reply, i updated the question

Comment: "Why is this query not working" - always describe *how* it is not working. Does it give a compile error? Runtime error? Some other result than expected, if so what result?

Comment: `GROUP BY >>>u<<<.name`

Comment: it tells me that i cant return the company name because it is not contained in the aggregate function

Comment: @user3127554 iam having doubt like UserCompany having cloumn having UserID column data type varchar and  User Table having userid  datatype as int is it correct ?

Comment: Of course it does tell you that error. Take another look at my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I've recreated your sample tables so we can use them in SSMS;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#User') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #User
CREATE TABLE #User (UserID int, Name nvarchar(4), Type int)
INSERT INTO #User (UserID, Name, Type)
VALUES
 (1,'John',1)
,(2,'Beth',2)
,(3,'Mike',5)
,(4,'John',5)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Company') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Company
CREATE TABLE #Company (CompanyID int, Name nvarchar(3))
INSERT INTO #Company (CompanyID, Name)
VALUES
 (1,'XYZ')
,(2,'KBC')
,(3,'MMM')
```

I had to guess at your column headers as they're not in the sample data. This was interesting as I guessed that the table `UserCompany` had the UserID and CompanyID in the same order as the title. When I looked at this it shows that you don't have user 3 in the data at all. For the purposes of this I'm going to assume that it's actually CompanyID and UserID in that order.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#UserCompany') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #UserCompany
CREATE TABLE #UserCompany (CompanyID int, UserID int)
INSERT INTO #UserCompany (CompanyID, UserID)
VALUES
 (1,1)
,(1,3)
,(1,4)
,(2,3)
,(2,1)
```

Assuming that's correct, you'll want to do something like this;

```
SELECT
    c.Name AS Company_Name
    ,COUNT(u.UserID) Employees
FROM #Company c
INNER JOIN #UserCompany uc 
    ON c.CompanyID = uc.CompanyID
INNER JOIN #User u 
    ON uc.UserID = u.UserID
    AND u.Type = 5
GROUP BY c.Name
HAVING Count(u.UserID) > 1
```

Which will give you the output;

```
Company_Name    Employees
XYZ             2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just update the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT UC.companyID 
FROM USER u JOIN 
     UserCompany UC 
     ON u.UserID = UC.UserID JOIN 
     Company C 
     ON uc.companyID = c.companyID
GROUP BY UC.companyID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN U.TYPE = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;
```